# how to change url when button is pressed in swift

Tags: swift

I'm having  2 buttons button1 & button2
when button1 is pressed I have to get url1 and when button2 is pressed get url2 in the below function

```
           func fetchXMLData() {
    XMLParserFactory.fetchData(url: "https://brwterrgn.ergwgw.com/etwtt.cms") { (listOfXMLVM, error) in

        print("Fetch xml data")
        if error == nil {
            self.listOfNewsVM = listOfXMLVM!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the url a parameter and change it from the caller place

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    fetchXMLData(url: "https://value.com/etwtt.cms")
}

func buttonAct(_ sender: UIButton) {
    fetchXMLData(url: "https://brwterrgn.ergwgw.com/etwtt.cms")
} 
func fetchXMLData(url:String) {
    XMLParserFactory.fetchData(url:url) { (listOfXMLVM, error) in

        print("Fetch xml data")
        if error == nil {
            self.listOfNewsVM = listOfXMLVM!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    func showSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let sec = //
        sec.delegate = self
        present/push(sec)

    }

    func fetchXMLData(url:String) { 
        XMLParserFactory.fetchData(url:url) { (listOfXMLVM, error) in

            print("Fetch xml data")
            if error == nil {
                self.listOfNewsVM = listOfXMLVM!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            }
        }
}


class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate:FirstVC?

    func buttonAct(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.fetchXMLData(url: "https://brwterrgn.ergwgw.com/etwtt.cms")
    }

}
```

Comment: but buttons are in one vc1 and fetchdata function is in vc2 ,i mean one view to other view

Comment: then you need a reference to that vc inside the current one , you need a delegate

Comment: pls bro explain in brief if possible with example

Comment: @PalagiriNoorudin why did you not mention that vital piece of information in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter to this fetchXMLData function

```
func fetchXMLData(withUrl url: String)
```

also replace your url by this url variable

```
XMLParserFactory.fetchData(url: url)
```

Now in every IBAction call this function with different url passed as parameter of this method

```
@IBAction func button1pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    fetchXMLData(withUrl: "url1.com")
}

@IBAction func button2pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    fetchXMLData(withUrl: "url2.com")
}
```